# Accuracy of LocationManager vs Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I have been using LocationManager/LocationClient which doesnt give me highly accurate results obviously because of not being able to use GPS. Based on Location Services setting ON, I get location which isn't highly accurate.
But with Apps like Uber,TaxiForSure without using GPS they are able to plot my location on Google Maps with high accuracy.

So is there a secret sauce in Google Maps API? I mean is Google Maps API doing something more than just LocationManager/LocationClient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has build a Database which links WLAN BSSIDs to a geographic location. A BSSID is like the MAC Address of a access point that gets broadcasted by that access point. It is therefore "public viewable" if the BSSID broadcast is enabled, which is the default for most access points. The BSSID operates on a lower layer as the IP stack, you don't even have to be connected to an access point to receive these broadcasts.

Every time you run Google Maps or Navigation with enabled GPS and WiFi and if your device is able to get a good GPS fix, the current visible WLAN networks and your current location (the GPS fix) are uploaded to Google to build and update the database. This technique is sometimes called crowdsourcing. Every Android device acts therefore as data collector.

Since most access points are static in their position and only cover a small area - the coverage radius is approximately 100m - they are ideal anchors for a good location fix without GPS.

Plus Google StreetView cars also carries a GPS and Wifi for the same purpose

Comment: Is it for the Google Play Services Fused API or Google Maps for Android API . Does Google Play Services Fused API also receive the location based upon above logic. Can you point a resource/link?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6fa9ad4afcd762aea519ff61811386c23d18ddb2/packages/FusedLocation/src/com/android/location/fused/FusionEngine.java they are using LocationManager only